# How to find top friends on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to develop an application on facebook for which i need those friends with whom the user interacts the most on facebook .In short i need a list of top friends of a user. How can i do that.What parameters do i need to look for in the graph api for finding the top friends.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook doesn't provide this information directly per se but it would be pretty easy to use FQL statements to generate this information yourself.  Check out the [FQL documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) asn you could run queries against the [stream](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) table to find user interactions.   You could also look at checkin table and album/photo/photo_tag, although these would require more permissions from the user.